# Draw a shape that tracks my finger

Tags: android, drawing, android-canvas

I know how to draw paths on a canvas and understand how to undo/redo. But now I want to draw shapes (lines, circles, rectangles) that dynamically resize depending on how I drag them - just like we have in MS Paint.

If I use "drawLine", the line is there permanently with no way of erasing it and redrawing it to my new finger location. Same with circle as I want the circle to constantly change width as I drag my finger. So the old one has to erased (keeping all the other paths on the bitmap intact) and the new one drawn in its place.

Been searching a lot for this, but haven't come across how t do it. Maybe I'm using the wrong keywords, but I don't know. Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to do it. I misunderstood the way the offscreen drawing thing worked. The idea is to write to the bitmap only after you have the shape you want - ie on "touch up". Till then, draw the shape using the "canvas" object in on Draw...

Answer (score 0):

Each time you move the finger, call the underlying view's invalidate() function, it will trigger erasing the entire background

public void invalidate ()
Since: API Level 1

Invalidate the whole view. If the view is visible, onDraw(android.graphics.Canvas) will be called at some point in the future. This must be called from a UI thread. To call from a non-UI thread, call postInvalidate().

Then redraw your shape based on your finger's new position.

Comment: I already call invalidate while drawing other stuff. When in "shape" mode, if I call Canvas.drawRect, then the change will be made permanent.